# Using reduce() with an inferred return type

Tags: swift, reduce

Given:

```
let a = [1, 2, 3]
```

Use reduce() to map to an array of strings:

```
let b: [String] = a.reduce([], { $0 + [String($1)] })
```

This returns ["1", "2", "3"] as you'd expect.

```
let c: [String] = a.reduce([], { $0 + [$1] })
```

This generates a compiler error (can't convert from Int to String), also as you'd expect.

```
let d = a.reduce([String](), { $0 + [$1] })
```

This returns [1, 2, 3] of type Array<Any>. Why doesn't the compiler consider the Result type to be Array<String>, and also generate an error in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want an error to occur (and I think a warning is in order), but the compiler assumes you want code to compile, instead. So it's going to fall back to `Any` for heterogenous collections, unless you type it otherwise. E.g.

```swift
protocol Protocol { }
extension Bool: Protocol { }
extension Int: Protocol { }

[[true]].reduce([0], +) as [any Protocol]
```

The correct return type can be inferred. Just not if you create a heterogeneous result.

```swift
a.map(String.init)
a.reduce(into: [String]()) { $0.append(.init($1)) }
a.reduce(into: []) { $0.append(String($1)) }
```

Comment: I like this phrase “the compiler assumes you want code to compile”

Answer (score 1):

`[Any]` is a type of array that can contain `1`, `2` and `3`. When you try to append those values to `[String]` it just turns it into `[Any]`.

It doesn't work on the other case because you're asking for the final array to be `[String]` by using it on the declaration.

```
let a = // array of [Int] ✅
let b: [String] = // array of [String] ✅
let c: [String] = // array of [Any] ❌
let d = // array of [Any] ✅
```

Comment: Right, I understand b and c. But the declaration for reduce is:

`func reduce<Result>(_ initialResult: Result, _ nextPartialResult: (Result, Self.Element) throws -> Result) rethrows -> Result`. So in the absence of a declared type for the return value, why doesn't the compiler see the actual type of Result here as Array<String> (based on initialResult) and flag an error? I've explicitly told it that the initial value is an Array<String>, not an Array<Any>.

Comment: There are 3 instances of `Result` in that signature (besides the declaration). By doing something like `let c: [String]` you're forcing `Result` to be `[String]`, there's no other type that can fit. If you just do `reduce([String]()...`, that's only one of the uses of `Result`, but there are two more, and the compiler will infer a type that can encapsulate all 3.